# access a variable from RecyclerView#Adapter class

Tags: android

I have a class extends RecyclerView#Adapter called `RecordAdapter`. I implement OnClickListener for my icon in the list for delete the specific list of data, here is my code:

```
@Override
public RecordAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    final Context context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    View contactView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_record, parent, false);

    RecordAdapter.ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(contactView, new RecordAdapter.ViewHolder.IMyViewHolderClicks()
    {
        public void onDelete(final ImageView callerImage)
        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .setTitle("Delete Record")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this record (Uuid" + callerImage.getTag() + ")?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                        {
                            MainActivity.delete(callerImage.getTag().toString());
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();
        }
    });
    return vh;
}
```

On user click on the delete icon, system will pop out an confirmation dialog which u can see from the code above. Here the problem, if user confirm to delete the data, I need to access the variable in my `Activity` class which is `MainActivity.class` to delete the specific data from the `ArrayList` named `record`. How I do this is set the`record` variable to static and make it able to access from adapter class like this:

```
static ArrayList<Record> record = new ArrayList<>();
static RecordAdapter adapter;
public static void delete(String tag)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < record.size(); i++)
    {
        if(record.get(i).getUuid().equals(tag))
        {
            record.remove(i);
            adapter.notifyItemRemoved(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

It works perfectly, however, it doesn't look like a good practice, is there any better approach?

Comment: you can delete that record directly from adapter class form record model and then adapter.notifyItemRemoved(i);

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface

```
public interface OnRecyclerItemClickListener {
public void onItemClicked(Object object, View view, int position);

public void onItemLongClicked(Object object, View view, int position);
}
```

Create an instance of **OnRecyclerItemClickListener** in Adapter class

```
holder.deleteImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(OnRecyclerItemClickListener!=null){
                        OnRecyclerItemClickListener.onItemClicked(your_model_or_data,view, position);
}
            }
        });
```

And in Main Activity

```
adapter.setOnRecyclerItemClickListener(new OnRecyclerItemClickListener{
    public void onItemClicked(Object object, View view, int position){
        //implement you alert dialog or code 
    }

    public void onItemLongClicked(Object object, View view, int position);
    }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your Activity implement some interface, which has method `onDelete(int position)` like following:

```
interface OnDeleteListener {
    void onDelete(int position);
}

public class MyActivity extends ... inplements OnDeleteListener {
    ...

    void onDelete(String tag) {
        for (int i = 0; i < record.size(); i++)
        {
            if(record.get(i).getUuid().equals(tag))
            {
                record.remove(i);
                adapter.notifyItemRemoved(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then in your adapter

```
public class RecordAdapter ... {
    public void setOnDeleteListener(OnDeleteListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }


    ...


                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                        {
                            listener.onDelete(callerImage.getTag().toString());
                        }

}
```

and after you create adapter do `adapter.setOnDeleteListener(this);`